# Обращение к элементам итератора

Tags: python

С помощью данной конструкции из xml документа получаю список элементов:

```
for element in root.iter('P'):
    print element
```

Как можно обратиться (изменить, удалить) к определённому элементу и его значению из этого списка отдельно, чтобы не менять весь список?

Пробую поменять значение 0-го индекса на 1 так

```
mylist = list(root.iter('P'))
mylist[0] = '1'
print mylist[0]
```

выдаёт ошибку

> print mylist[0] = '1'
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Пытаюсь записать изменённое значение обратно в документ

```
from xml.dom.minidom import *
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import ConfigParser

conf = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
conf.read('C:\config.conf')# Путь до файла указывается в конфиге

path = conf.get('Path:', 'path')
    
xml2 = parse(path)
tree = ET.parse(path)
root = tree.getroot()

xml2 = xml2.getElementsByTagName('P')

P = xml2[0].firstChild.data
    
mylist = list(root.iter('P'))
mylist[0] = '1'
print mylist[0]
tree.write(path)
```

Comment: Любой конечный (finite) итератор можно дезитерировать в список или кортеж: `mylist=list(root.iter('P'))`. Теперь у вас есть обычный список, к элементам которого можно обратиться по индексу.

Comment: @strawdog а как можно поменять элемент из списка если так mylist.text = '1' то пишет AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text' ?

Comment: Вы неправильно обращаетесь к элементам списка. К ним нужно обращаться по индексу: mylist[1] = '1'. А уж найти индекс нужного элемента - ваша забота

Comment: @strawdog с поиском мне всё ясно я его нахожу так как вы написали. Я его поменять не знаю как, а после мне эти изменения нужно записать в документ.

Comment: @strawdog пробую поменять значение 0-го индекса на 1 так mylist[0] = '1' то пишет SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните свой вопрос кодом, который вы дописали, а так же текстом ошибки (нажмите на ссылку "править" под текстом вопроса").

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку **и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе**.

Comment: @strawdog добавил

Comment: Если у вас pyhton версии выше 3, то синтаксис оператора `print` таков: `print(mylist[0])` Сначала присваиваете значение: `mylist[0] = '1'`, а затем выводите его на печать: `print(mylist[0])`

Comment: `print mylist[0] = '1'` - ну так это и есть syntax error. Попробуй вместо него тот код, который написал в вопросе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myiterator = iter(range(10, 20)) # какой-то итератор для примера

mylist = list(myiterator) #деитурируем
print(mylist)
```

> [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

```
mylist[1] = 'a' #присваиваем новое значение элементу
print(mylist)
```

> [10, 'a', 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]

**UPDATE**:
Как выяснилось, автору вопроса нужно внести изменения в элементы разобранного .xml файла.

Для этого не нужно выводить итератор элемента root в какой-то дополнительный список, можно сразу работать с его тегами по приведенному ниже [примеру](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#modifying-an-xml-file):

```
for rank in root.iter('rank'):
    new_rank = int(rank.text) + 1
    rank.text = str(new_rank)
    rank.set('updated', 'yes')

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Этот код, разумеется, нужно модифицировать под свои данные.
Если вы хотите изменить какие-то определенные представители этого тега, и знаете их очередность, например 1-й и 5-й, то можно изменить код так:

```
i=1
for elem in root.iter('P'):
    if i in [1,5]: #1-й и 5-й       
        elem.text = '1'
        elem.set('updated', 'yes')
    i+=1

tree.write('output.xml')
```

Comment: да всё верно заработало, а как записать измененный индекс обратно в документ я пользуюсь этим методом tree.write(path), но он не меняет в данном случае ?

Comment: Дополняйте свой вопрос, чем больше кода вы приведете, тем легче нам будет вам помочь. Из комментариев мало что понятно.

Comment: Дополнил свой вопрос.

Comment: Это не "дополнение", это непонятный кусок кода. Что за tree.write? Откуда взялась переменная path, если в приведенном вами коде она не фигурирует больше нигде? Как она связана с mylist? Вы xml разбираете?

Comment: Извините, но это не совсем то я меняю значение у всех тегов 'P' а мне нужно из этой кучи выбрать один или два как вариант я думал положить их в список так как у них появляются индексы по которым можно выбрать тот тег который нужно изменить и после изменённый записать обратно в документ на тоже место.

Comment: @VargSieg мой пример был призван лишь показать, что с элементом root можно работать напрямую, без копирования его содержимого в дополнительный список

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как реализовать в данном условии if i in [1,5]: не через запятую шла замена, а указать цифру например if i in [5]: и 5 й элемент меняется ? Просто в  случае  if i in [1,2,3,4,5]: работает только так что бы поменять 5-й элемент надо поменять или пройти 4 предыдущих.

Comment: @VargSieg, ну , очевидно, `if i==5:`

Comment: Спасибо вам большое то что нужно.